According to Hindu scriptures, what happens to our soul spiritually and karmically when we have sexual intercourse?
According to Hindu scriptures, what happens to our soul spiritually and karmically when we have sexual intercourse?
Will there be a karmic bond created between us and our sexual partner during sexual intercourse?
If yes, how will this karmic bond affect us spiritually and karmically?
Thank you.
